# Using ASP.NET Membership API with layered architecture, DDD etc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, asp.net-membership

I am trying to improve my Architecture approach with Application Development (MVC specifically), ie following loosely coupled approach with interfaces, repositories etc.

With this in mind I'm not sure what the best approach is to tackle the use of (or not to use) the built in ASP.NET Membership API.

When following a layered architecture is it best to do your own Membership or use/wrap/abstract the existing ASP.NET Membership API?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a concern you should take up now.

I worked on many applications based on the same approaches as you (layered architecture, DDD...) and my advice would be to think firstly of your domain and business logic.
For the membership, I would use one of the builtin solutions that the framework gives you. It would be an accelerator to your development (as many frameworks indeed)

The good point is that you talk of layered architecture, don't hesitate to create the necessary abstractions to change your membership system anytime you need that later.